# Need help with corrected SQL syntax for Northwind Data Access Layer tutorial

Tags: sql, syntax, northwind

I am attempting to complete the Data Access Layer tutorial  from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx I have so far (thanks to this forum) be able to generate the appropriate TableAdapter and they work on the single tables. Now, I am attempting to do the related tables query which modifies the GetProducts() method by editing the SQL to a nested select format looking at three tables; Products, Catageories, and Suppliers. The syntax given is as follows:

```
SELECT     
 ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, 
 QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder, 
 ReorderLevel, Discontinued,
    (SELECT 
        CategoryName 
     FROM Categories 
     WHERE Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID  as CategoryName, 
    (SELECT 
       CompanyName 
     FROM Suppliers 
     WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID) as SupplierName
FROM Products
```

This does not parse. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax for this nested select such that it will work? Has anyone else had this problem? I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 Express.
Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing a closing paren for the 1st subquery, change;

```
... Products.CategoryID as CategoryName
```

to

```
... Products.CategoryID) as CategoryName
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the first "(" (or possibly the second depending on how you look at it).

Comment: Thank you so much, that has solved the problem. Onward and Upward.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT     
 ProductID, 
 ProductName, 
 SupplierID, 
 CategoryID, 
 QuantityPerUnit, 
 UnitPrice, 
 UnitsInStock, 
 UnitsOnOrder, 
 ReorderLevel, 
 Discontinued,
 Categories.CategoryName as CategoryName,
 Suppliers.CompanyName As SupplierName
FROM Products
Join Suppliers On Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
Join Categories On Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
```

You want to use a Join here instead of a nested query

Comment: I prefer joins however the tutorial states: If you update the GetProducts() SELECT using JOIN syntax the DataSet Designer won't be able to auto-generate the methods for inserting, updating, and deleting database data using the DB direct pattern. Instead, you'll have to manually create them much like we did with the InsertProduct method earlier in this tutorial. Furthermore, you'll manually have to provide the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand property values if you want to use the batch updating pattern.

I haven't tried it using the join but will do so. Thanks for the reply.